# Compiling Android on 32bit Linux not possible?

Tags: cross-compiling, android-source, android-build, build-environment

In the Cyanogenmod Wiki about [compiling CM Android](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Build_for_i9100) I read that a 64bit environment (Linux) is necessary to build recent Android versions. Is that true?

1. Which step would fail on 32bit?
2. Why can’t a 32bit system work there?

Answer (score 1):

At a guess, a 32-bit system would run out of RAM during linking. I recall reading about this problem with regard to compiling Chromium.

Answer (score 0):

Referring to http://source.android.com/source/initializing.html

Setting up a Linux build environment

These instructions apply to all branches, including master.

The Android build is routinely tested in house on recent versions of Ubuntu LTS (10.04), but most distributions should have the required build tools available. Reports of successes or failures on other distributions are welcome.

For Gingerbread (2.3.x) and newer versions, including the master branch, a 64-bit environment is required. Older versions can be compiled on 32-bit systems.

Note: It is also possible to build Android in a virtual machine. If you are running Linux in a virtual machine, you will need at least 16GB of RAM/swap and 30GB or more of disk space in order to build the Android tree.

Comment: Okay, it’s true. – Does this answer 1. or 2.?